# Limit of functional fraction where the denominator goes to zero.

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to-3^+} \frac{x+2}{x+3}$

What can I do with a limit such as this. I can not factor, nor can I plug in the limit number. I tried to multiply the entire equation by $-1$, but that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The limit does not exists!! Is #/0.

Comment: If you Google `(x+2)/(x+3)`, it gives you a graph of the function. The graph suggests (correctly) that the limit is equal to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can trace in following way:

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+}\frac{x+2}{x+3}=\lim_{x\to 3^+}(1-\frac{1}{x+3})=1-\lim_{x\to 3^+}\frac{1}{x+3}=1-\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{1}{t}=-\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x + 3 \to 0^{+}$, and $x + 2 \to -1$. Thus $\dfrac{x+2}{x+3} \to -\infty$